# Using express to generate output .... for JSON output

Tags: node.js, express

- I am using Async response to get the output
- I am using express
- I am also combining two table data into single JSON response

**express program::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); 

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxx',
    password: "xxx",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); 

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8084);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var first, second;

    async.series( [

        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM test1', function(err, rows, fields)

                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        first = JSON.stringify(rows);
                        callback();
                });
        },

        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM test2', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    second = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    callback();
            });
        }

   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'first' : first,
        'second' : second
    });
} );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**What code changes do i need to make here**

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your following function:

```
function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'first' : first,
        'second' : second
    });
}
```

to

```
function ( error, results ) {
    // case 1: since results is a js array object you can do following and is recommended
    res.json({first: results[0], second: results[0]});
    // case 2:else you can do the following thing as well. (Not recommended in this case of async)
    /* var jsonObj = JSON.parse('{first :' + first +', second : ' + second + '}');
    response.json(jsonObj); */
}
```

The following will be the output:

```
{
  first :[{"_id":1,"name":"devrath","age":24},{"_id":2,"name":"Dheeraj","age":25},{"_id":3,"name":"Vikas","age":26}], 
  second : [{"_id":1,"place":"Hassan","phone":1},{"_id":2,"place":"Pune","phone":2},{"_id":3,"place":"Delhi","phone":3}]
}
```

In your function actually the variables are of type string (not object), so you need to parse it to JSON before sending response(as in case2). But what actually you forgot the `results` object itself which contains all the results in array for all your `async.series functions`, so better you take that as mentioned in `case 1` use `results[0]` for `first` and `results[1]` for `second` (In this case you can ignore storing in variable itself like you did `first = JSON.stringify(rows);`)

For your information, you are consider `Content-Type` to set before responding. for more check the express [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json)

Comment: it's great that you modified your answer on code based from answer below :)

Comment: Anyways we are trying to help each other only.. Thanks for updates.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `stringify` the results from MySql driver. Moreover, you don't need to store the results into variables, since that exactly what `async.js` does for you.

So, the code should look like:

```
var tasks = ['test1', 'test2'].map(function (table) {
  return function (callback) {
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM ' + table, function (err, rows) {
         if (err) {
           return callback(err);
         }

         callback(null, rows);
     });
  }
});

async.series(tasks, function (err, results) {
   if (err) {
     return res.send(500);
   }

   res.json({first: results[0], second: results[1]});
});
```

Comment: I guess 'second' should refer index 1 from results object, if i am not wrong `second: results[1]`